# Bounding box offset after call to function setTop and renderall;

Tags: fabricjs

```
<body>
<canvas   id="canvas" width="1024" height="700" style="border:2px solid #000000"></canvas>
</body>

<script>


canvas.add(pointA);
var pointA = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 4, id:"A", fill: 'red', left: 650, top: 210,hasControls:false,padding:5});

pointA.setTop(40).setLeft(40);
canvas.renderAll();

</script>
```

After I call function renderAll(); I can not select circle anymore(bounding box is somwere else on canvas), how to fix that  ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `setCoords();` should fix the issue.

```
   <script>


    canvas.add(pointA);
    var pointA = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 4, id:"A", fill: 'red', left: 650, top: 210,hasControls:false,padding:5});

    pointA.setTop(40).setLeft(40);
 setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();

    </script>
```